# Context switching is too expensive

Tags: android, performance, android-mediacodec

I am writing a video processing app and have come across the following performance issue:
Most of the methods in my app have great differences between cpu time and real time.

I have investigated using the DDMS TraceView and have discovered that the main culprit for these discrepancies is context switching in some base methods, *such as MediaCodec.start()* or *MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()*

*MediaCodec.start()* for example has 0.7ms Cpu time and 24.2ms Real time. 97% of this real time is used up by the context switch.[image]

This would not be a real problem, but the method is called quite often, and it is not the only one that presents this kind of symptom.

I also need to mention that all of the processing happens in a single AsyncTask, therefore on a single non-UI thread.

Is context switching a result of poor implementation, or an inescapable reality of threading?

I would very much appreciate any advice in this matter.

Answer (score 4):

First, I doubt the time is actually spent context-switching.  MediaCodec.start() is going to spend some amount of time waiting for the mediaserver process to talk to the video driver, and that's probably what you're seeing.  (Unless you're using a software codec, your process doesn't do any of the actual work -- it sends IPC requests to mediaserver, which talks to the hardware codec.)  It's possible traceview is just reporting its best guess at where the time went.

Second, AsyncTask threads are executed at a [lower priority](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-mr1-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#293).  Since MediaCodec should be doing all of the heavy lifting in the hardware codec, this won't affect throughput, but it's possible that it's having some effect on latency because other threads will be prioritized by the scheduler.  If you're worried about performance, stop using AsyncTask.  Either do the thread management yourself, or use the handy helpers in [java.util.concurrent](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Third, if you really want to know what's happening when multiple threads and processes are involved, you should be using [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html), not traceview.  An example of using systrace with custom trace markers (to watch CPU cores spin up) can be found [here](http://bigflake.com/systrace/).

Comment: Hello @fadden and thank you for your response. I have a question though:
How can i check if i'm using a software codec or a hardware one? I am configuring the codec like so:

String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        try {
            decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        decoder.configure(format, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);

The video i'm decoding is a standard android camera mp4 video

Comment: You can usually tell by looking at the codec's name, e.g. "OMX.google.h264.encoder" is software, while "OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc" is hardware. I don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: The codec is indeed hardware. OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc. So i guess there's nothing i can really try. I've moved the processing to a default priority  thread with ExecutorService but it didn't really help.